# Change of formats of Headers on tables, images and charpers, other words or idioms

Tags: tables, graphics, header-footer, customize

there!
I want change the capture of headers on tables and images for another names cause i want wrote other word in other idiom. for example:
Table12 -> Tabla12
Image5 -> Imagen5
in

""
\begin{table}[H]

```
\caption{\\Transiciones de referencia del hafmio al renio, $keV$.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c c c c c }
     \hline
     Z & Elem. & $L_{\alpha_1}$ & $L_{\alpha_2}$ & $L_{\beta_1}$ & $L_{\beta_2}$ & $L_{\gamma_1}$ & $L_{Iab}$ & $L_{IIab}$ & $L_{IIIab}$ \\
      \hline 
     72 & Hf & 7.898 & 7.843 & 9.021 & 9.346 & 10.514 & 11.264 & 10.734 & 9.556 \\
     
     73 & Ta & 8.145 & 8.087 & 9.341 & 9.649 & 10.892 & 11.676 & 11.130 & 9.876 \\
     
     74 & W & 8.396 & 8.333 & 9.670 & 9.959 & 11.283 & 12.090 & 11.535 & 10.198 \\
      
     75 & Re & 8.651 & 8.584 & 10.008 & 10.273 & 11.684 & 12.522 & 11.955 & 10.531 \\
              
      \hline
      
\end{tabular}

\label{tab:rxweighter2}
```

\end{table}""

this code run for a table that header say:

**Table3 Transiciones de referencia del hafmio al renio, *keV*.**

i want this:

**Tabla3 Transiciones de referencia del hafmio al renio, *keV*.**

and the other tables header go on the numbering (Tabla1, Tabla2, Tabla3,...).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you add `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` then all fixed texts such as `Table` will be spanish not English

Comment: https://www.learnlatex.org/es/language-01

Comment: the use of \userpackage[spanish]{babel} change the headers form:

table'number'

to:

cuadro'number'

want:

tabla'number'
   thanks for help.

Comment: did I pick the wrong language or just a different word, anyway `\renewcommand\tablename{tabla}`  almost every such generated text has a `\....name` command with just the word and no formatting to allow translation.

Comment: Why do you have `\\ ` at the start of a caption?

Comment: Yes I have \\, is a edit proof not error alert message give and i don't end this work.